# How to create folder in internal storage and save captured image

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

I want to capture image and save it to specific folder in internal storage. Currently i am able to open intent and get thumbnail of captured image. I dont want to user extrnal stotage as now mostly users use their internal storage and not sd card.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
    startActivityForResult(intent,1);
}


  @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(LeaveApplicationCreate.this);
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_image,attachView, false);

        ImageView img = view.findViewById(R.id.img);
        AppCompatImageView btnRemove = view.findViewById(R.id.btnRemove);
        img.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);

        btnRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                attachView.removeView(view);
            }
        });

        attachView.addView(view);

        File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/Digimkey/Camera/");
        if (!directory.exists()) {
            directory.mkdir();
        }
        File file = new File(directory, System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg");


        try (FileOutputStream out =new FileOutputStream(file)) {
            imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Since you have successfully gotten the image, you can just use OpenFileOutput (with the Serializable interface) to save it to internal storage.

Comment: "I dont want to user extrnal stotage as now mostly users use their internal storage and not sd card" -- [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/14/storage-situation-external-storage.html), from the standpoint of the Android SDK, is not [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/15/storage-situation-removable-storage.html). Users do not have direct access to what the Android SDK calls [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/13/storage-situation-internal-storage.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First gain Write Permissions.

```
File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), dirName);
        if (!directory.exists()) {
            directory.mkdirs();
          }
        File file = new File(directory, fileName);
         if (!file.exists()) {
          file.createNewFile();
        }

try (FileOutputStream out =new FileOutputStream(file)) {
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); 
 } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

There are two types of storage. 
1) Internal ex. "/root/.."
   Unless you have rooted device, we can't access. this path.
2) External ex. "/storage/emuated/0"
   Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
By using this path, we are able to create a directory/file.

Comment: But to create folder in internal storage and save image in it?

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: But it will save in extrnal storage not in internal storage

Comment: Means  at app Cache?

Comment: No. Internal Storage. I have to folder in Internal Storage like there Android,DCMI, like that and want to save in it.

Comment: The above code is the answer. what your are looking for. Unless your device is rooted, you can't access the Internal Storage.

Comment: There are already folders like WhatsApp, SnapChat is available in my internal Storage

Comment: Let me know, the problem your are facing with above code.

Comment: I want to make folder in Internal Storage not in Extrnal Storage.

Comment: I guess u r wrong here. I have WhastApp,SnapChat, ShareIt, Wink this folders available in my Internal Storage and my device is not rooted.

Comment: external storage here doesn't mean sd card, what you call `internal storage` is android `external storage` so @kashyap is right

Comment: I updated code in question, its not working as i dont have sd card.

Comment: ok i got it, my cncept was wrong. I thought getExternalDirectory is sdcard

Answer (score 0):

Use to method to save your bimap in local storage. Pass bimap image as parameter *i.e* ***saveToInternalStorage(imageBitmap)***

```
private String saveToInternalStorage(Bitmap bitmapImage){
    //set image saved path 
    File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        + "MyApp"+ "/Files");

      if (!storageDir.exists()) {
        storageDir.mkdirs();
      }
    File mypath=new File(storageDir,"bitmap_image.jpg");
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {           
        fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
        bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
    } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
          fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
    return directory.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

Required permissions in Manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: This specific storage directory can be accessed via `File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(null);`

Comment: Yes you can use but getExternalFilesDirs(), which returns a File array with entries for each storage location.

Comment: It is not possible to Create folder inside Internal Storage like WhatsApp, SnapChat creating?

Comment: yes you can, just use @kashyap answer. `dirName` would be `SnapChat`, `Whatsapp` or whatever you want